Partial integral over exponentiated polynomial
I'm interested in integrals of the form
$$F(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \; e^{a+bx+cy+dx^2+exy+fy^2+gx^3+hx^2y+jxy^2+ky^3}\;.$$
Here, $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k$ are complex numbers, where $g,h,j,k$ are purely imaginary, and
$$\begin{pmatrix}\operatorname{real}(d)&\operatorname{real}(e)\\\operatorname{real}(e)&\operatorname{real}(f)\end{pmatrix}>0\;.$$
So this is a partial integral of a Gaussian function in two variables, with additional 3rd order phase terms.
Question: Is $F$ of the form $F(y)=e^{P(y)}$ for some polynomial $P$ of finite degree? If $g=0$, then this is true for $P$ being 4th order (since then this is still a Gaussian integral in $x$). I suppose in general the answer is "no", but I don't know how to do the integral, and numeric experiment is a bit tricky too.
